# BITMAPFILEHEADER not linked?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I compile a c-program using MinGW

```
C:\MinGW64\mingw64\bin\g++ -shared 
     -IC:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\include 
     -IC:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\include\win32
   test.h -o test.dll
```

Ok. this code compiles and runs good:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Bar_doFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject o){
   printf("hi!");
}
```

Output is `hi!`.

---

This code compiles good, but does not run.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Bar_doFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject o){
   printf("hi!");
   BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Peter\Documents\workspace\Bar\foo.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at Run.<init>(Run.java:17)
    at Run.<clinit>(Run.java:14)
    at Run.main(Run.java:9)
```

I guess i need to link some more. Any Idea? Can i do it by using `LoadLibrary("*.dll")`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i got it.

I have to download http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and it sais i need

- libstdc++-6.dll
- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

in the same directory.

Now it works fine.